Dataform: JavaScript constant becoming undefined
Background
I am using Google Cloud's Dataform for data processing.
I have standardized constant definitions and SQL rendering functions in JavaScript, which are called from the sqlx file.
I can reference the constants defined in JavaScript from the .sqlx  as expected, some constants are becoming undefined.
I don't know the cause and need help.
Example code
example.js
const CONST_STRING_01 = "hoge";
const CONST_STRING_02 = "fuga";
// and more. 40+

const CONST_MAP_01 = {"A": "A-", "B": null}
const CONST_MAP_02 = {"X": "X-", "Y": "Y-", "Z": "Z-"}
const CONST_MAP_03 = {"1": null, "2": null}
// and more. 20+

function render_function_01 (map) {
    let renderedCaseSQL = "(generate a when clause from map)";
    return renderedSQL;
}
// and more.

module.exports {
    CONST_STRING_01,
    CONST_STRING_02,
    // and more string constants. (40+)
    CONST_MAP_01,
    CONST_MAP_02,
    CONST_MAP_03,
    // and more map constants. (20+)
    render_function_01,
    // and more functions.
}

example.sqlx
config {
    type: "table",
    schema: "example_schema",
    name: "example_transform",
}

SELECT
    ${example.CONST_STRING_01} AS column_a,
    CASE input_b ${example.render_function_01(example.CONST_MAP_01)} END AS column_b,
    CASE input_c ${example.render_function_01(example.CONST_MAP_02)} END AS column_c,
    CASE input_d ${example.render_function_01(example.CONST_MAP_03)} END AS column_d,
FROM
    ${ref("example_schema", "example_input_table")}

Expected behavior
The value of the constant defined in example.js can be correctly referenced from example.sqlx
System behavior
Most constants can retrieve their defined values. However, some constants becoming undefined.
I am creating multiple combinations of similar .js and .sqlx.
It only occurs in .js with a large number of constant definitions.

example

CONST_STRING_01 -> OK
CONST_STRING_02 -> OK
and more string constants. (40+) -> OK
CONST_MAP_01 -> OK
CONST_MAP_02 -> undefined
CONST_MAP_03 -> OK
// and more map constants. (20+) -> Just one undefined, others OK



Checked

No compile errors in example.js
No compile errors in example.sqlx

but, since the constant is undefined, it results in SQL syntax error


constant and function names are unique
module.exports contains the correct constant name
usage limit of Dataform

not problem
link

https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/dataform-core
https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/quotas





Try

Copy example.js to create example2.js. in example.sqlx reference example2.js

Succeed temporarily. But sometimes errors suddenly occur while modifying .js or .sqlx


change the constant name (example: CONST_MAP_02 => CONST_MAP_02a）

Succeed temporarily. But sometimes errors suddenly occur while modifying .js or .sqlx


I created a function that simply returns a MAP to String and checked it.

